# How do I create a countdown for 4, 7, 8 seconds separately for the respective instructions

Tags: python

```
import time 

def print_breathing_exercise():
    instructions = [["Inhale through nose for four seconds.", 4],
                ["Now, hold your breath for seven seconds.", 7],
                ["Finally, exhale through the mouth for eight seconds.", 8]              
    ]

    for message, seconds in instructions:
        print(message)
        time.sleep(seconds)

print_breathing_exercise()
```

Comment: This code works for me. What change are you trying to make?

Answer (score 1):

Add a loop to decrement second by second:

```
import time 
def print_breathing_exercise():
    instructions = [["Inhale through nose for four seconds.", 4],
                ["Now, hold your breath for seven seconds.", 7],
                ["Finally, exhale through the mouth for eight seconds.", 8]              
    ]
    for message, seconds in instructions:
        print(message)
        for n in range(seconds, 0, -1):
            print(f'{n}..', end=' ')
            time.sleep(1)
        print()
print_breathing_exercise()
```

Output:

```
Inhale through nose for four seconds.
4.. 3.. 2.. 1..
Now, hold your breath for seven seconds.
7.. 6.. 5.. 4.. 3.. 2.. 1..
Finally, exhale through the mouth for eight seconds.
8.. 7.. 6.. 5.. 4.. 3.. 2.. 1..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a for loop which counts down from `seconds` and prints each second.

```py
import time 

def print_breathing_exercise():
    instructions = [["Inhale through nose for four seconds.", 4],
                ["Now, hold your breath for seven seconds.", 7],
                ["Finally, exhale through the mouth for eight seconds.", 8]              
    ]

    for message, seconds in instructions:
        print(message)
        for i in range(seconds, -1, -1):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)

print_breathing_exercise()
```

If you don't want to print `0` then you can change the for loop to `for i in range(seconds, 0, -1):`

I recommend looking up broader questions on stackoverflow first before asking for advice for your specific code.